# return PartialView with Ajax not inserting on page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0, asp.net-ajax

Just trying to wrap my head around the Ajax helper in Razor -- Probably overlooking something simple.

The following code is directing my current tab to /Music/SearchBand  rather than returning the partial to my div.

I've got this in my View:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("click me","SearchBand",
new AjaxOptions {
    UpdateTargetId = "replaceThisDiv"   
})

<div id="replaceThisDiv"></div>
```

And this in my controller:

```
public ActionResult SearchBand()
    {
        return PartialView("_bandResults");
    }
```

Comment: Have you included the `~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` in your view? Because this file contains the scripts required for the `@Ajax. ...` helpers.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you.  The textbook that I'm reading failed to mention that or show it in the header  =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Ajax. ...` helpers jut add some additional `data-` attributes to the generated HTML which in itself won't do any ajax requests (that's why the link "just" navigated to a different page).

To make it work porperly it needs some client side javascript functions which will fire the actual ajax requests with the use of the pregenerated `data-` attributes.

These js functions are in the `Sripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js` file:

So you need to include this JS file on every page where you plan to use any of the `@Ajax. ...` helpers:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" 
        type="text/javascript"></script>
```